# Explicit description of cohomology modules of a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb P^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am trying to understand the basics of sheaf cohomology, so I tried on a concrete example, but things are still very unclear to me...

Let $\mathscr F$ be the coherent subsheaf of $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^2}$ whose global sections are homogeneous polynomials of $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$ vanishing at $2$ given points $\mathbf a,\mathbf b\in\mathbb P^2$. Is there a way to describe explicitely the cohomology modules $H^1(\mathbb P^2,\mathscr F)$ and $H^2(\mathbb P^2,\mathscr F)$?

Comment: Have you tried computing the Cech complex with respect to the standard cover $D_+(x_0),D_+(x_1),D_+(x_2)$? This should be a nice exercise. If you need more hints, let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try. Actually, I will also try to simplify by replacing $\mathbb P^2$ by $\mathbb P^1$ (I'd like to understand the simplest possible non-trivial case).

Comment: You may also assume that $\mathbf{a}=[0:0:1]$ and $\mathbf{b}=[1:0:1]$ (since the automorphism group is $2$-transitive), in particular they lie both in $D_+(x_2)$. At least when your two points are assumed to be rational.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I finished computing the Cech complex for the sheaf $\mathscr F$ of functions vanishing at two points over $\mathbb P^1$ and I find $H^1(\mathbb P^1,\mathscr F)=k$. Would this be correct?

Comment: Dear @emeu, do  show your calculations in an answer to your own question: this is encouraged on this site. It will help assess  correctness and if so be  quite useful to others.

Comment: @emeu How can you give a coherent sheaf on $\Bbb{P}^2$ just by giving its global sections? This is only true if you're over an affine scheme, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Benja In this case, this is a subsheaf of the structure sheaf of $\mathbb P^2$ (whose global sections are homogeneous polynomials). So this definition seems to make sense since it describes the sheaf on all the affine charts, doesn't it?

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, I did not know that, thanks. I will post my computations as soon as possible.

Comment: @Benja To be sure that we agree on the definition on a subsheaf (for sheaves of abelian groups), here is the definition I use: $\mathscr F'$ is a subsheaf of $\mathscr F$ if for any open set $U$, $\mathscr F'(U)$ is a subgroup of $\mathscr F(U)$ (and everything is compatible with the restriction morphisms). So for instance for any subvariety $V$ of $\mathbb P^n$, there is a unique coherent subsheaf of $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}$ whose global sections are homogeneous polynomials vanishing on $V$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok now I understand that I was completely wrong when I was talking about the global sections of $\mathbb P^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\{a,b\}\subset \mathbb P^n\; (n\geq 1)$ be a two-point subset of $n$-dimensional projective space and $\mathcal F=\mathcal I_X$ the ideal sheaf of functions vanishing at $a$ and $b$.
This means that for an open subset $U\subset \mathbb P^n$ a section $s\in F(U)=\mathcal I_X(U)\subset \mathcal O(U)$ is a section in $\mathcal O(U)$ vanishing on $U\cap X$ (= a set  with $0,1$ or $2$ elements).
We then have an exact sequence of coherent sheaves on  $\mathbb P^n$: $$         0\to \mathcal I_X\to    \mathcal O_X \to Sky_X\to 0          $$ where $Sky_X$ is the sky scraper sheaf with stalk $k$  on $X$ and $0$ elsewhere.
Taking the associated cohomology long exact sequence we get $$0\to H^0(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal I_X)=0\to H^0(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal O_X)=k  \to H^0(\mathcal P^n,Sky_X)=k^2\to H^1(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal I_X)\to H^1(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal O_X)=0      $$ from which we immediately deduce the required dimension $\operatorname {dim} _k  H^1(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal I_X)=1$

As a check, notice that for $n=1$ we have $\mathcal I_X\cong\mathcal O(-2)$ and the equality $\operatorname {dim} _k  H^1(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O(-2))=1$ is easy to see, say by Serre duality.
Notice also that $n=1$ is the only value of $n$ for which $\mathcal I_X$ is an invertible sheaf (= line bundle)

**Edit**
A trivial modification of the above calculation shows that for a finite subset $X_r \subset \mathbb P^n$ with $r$ elements we have  $$\operatorname {dim} _k  H^1(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal I_{X_r})=r-1$$

Comment: Many thanks :)! Your answer is crystal clear. This skyscraper sheaf seems very interesting. Is there some good reference (accessible for a novice) on it?

Comment: Dear emeu, I'm glad this answer helped you. Sky scraper sheaves are defined in Hartshorne, Chapter II, Exercise 1.17. There isn't much to know about them, except for the important property that they are flabby and thus acyclic: they have no positive-dimensional cohomology.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some preliminary computations and a first attempt. Please let me know if you see mistakes.
To simplify, let $\mathbf a=(1:0)$ and $\mathbf b=(0:1)$ in $\mathbb P^1$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $\mathscr F$ be the ideal sheaf of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}$ vanishing on $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$.

I wish to compute the cohomology $H^1(\mathbb P^1,\mathscr F)$ via the Cech complex.

Let $\mathscr U=\{D_+(x),D_+(y)\}$ be the standard cover.
Clearly, the group of $2$-cochains is trivial and therefore $Z^1(\mathscr U,\mathscr F)=C^1(\mathscr U,\mathscr F)$, which is isomorphic to the abelian group $k[x]$

Let us compute the $1$-coboundaries. A $1$-cochain $f$ is a $1$-coboundary if there exists a $0$-cochain $h$ with
$f(D_+(x)\cap D_+(y))=h(D_+(y))_{|D_+(x)\cap D_+(y)} - h(D_+(x))_{|D_+(x)\cap D_+(y)}.$
Since $h$ is a $0$-cochain, we have that $h(D_+(x))$ is a polynomial in $k[y]$ vanishing at 0 and $h(D_+(y))$ is a polynomial in $k[x]$ vanishing at 0.

Taking into account the restriction maps, we obtain that $f$ is a $1$-coboundary iff $f(D_+(x)\cap D_+(y))$ is the restriction of a polynomial in $k[x]$ vanishing at $0$. Consequently, $B^1(\mathscr U,\mathscr F)$ is isomorphic to $x k[x]$ and therefore $H^1(\mathbb P^1,\mathscr F)=k[x]/xk[x]=k$.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't know what $\widetilde{(x,y)}$ is... What would be its definition? I am trying to compute the cohomology of the coherent sheaf $\mathscr F$ described above.

Comment: Dear emeu: yes, your calculation is correct.